# Xamarin access azure SQL database in shared code

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

Is there an easy way to access an Azure SQL Database in the shared code of a Xamarin PCL application? I am developing a cross-platform app that needs access to a shared set of data and I would like to write the code once rather than for each platform if possible.

Comment: You need to create an WebAPI that sit's in front of the database and the Xamarin app talks to that.